# iframe text input not working

Tags: iframe, cordova, zooming, textinput

I have loaded website into my phonegap application using iFrame.

```html
    <iframe id="divIFrame" src="https://mysite" border="0"></iframe>
```

I have used below css  to set zoom level of iFrame content

```css
       #divIFrame {
           -moz-transform: scale(0.45, 1.00);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.45, 1.00);
            -o-transform: scale(0.45, 1.00);
            -ms-transform: scale(0.45,1.00);
            transform: scale(0.45, 1.00);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
            -o-transform-origin: top left;
            -ms-transform-origin: top left;
            transform-origin: top left;
            border: solid #ccc 10px;
        }
```

After included the style to my iframe, I can't enter values into the textboxs in iframe content(mysite). The textbox, radio buttons are not working in mysite that loaded into iFrame.

The textboxs working fine when I remove above the zoom css. How to solve this issue? please help me..

Comment: the input fields not working when i resize the iframe content using this line -webkit-transform: scale(0.50). its working when i scale to (1.0) using -webkit-transform: scale(1.00)..  what might be problem? this is phonegap issue?

Comment: More likely a mobile safari issue - it is an unusual requirement, and mobile safari has somewhat limited iframe support.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, did you figure this out?